# Libgdx GestureDirector pan acting strangely when dealing with multiple fingers

Tags: libgdx, pan

I'm creating a game where the movement mechanics are meant to work like this: tap/hold the right side of the screen to accelerate in the direction you're facing and swipe either left or right on the left side of the screen to rotate. It works well enough until the player tries to rotate with a second finger while accelerating with the first. The pan method seems to still run with the second finger but very infrequently and the gdx.input.getX(i) if statements don't fire off. I'm using the pan method of the GestureDetector class. Here's a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmHI81ByPmU&feature=youtu.be

I looked at this similar question: [libgdx multiple pan events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799158/libgdx-multiple-pan-events) but the answers did not work for me, setting pan to return false did nothing, and the controls aren't related to buttons so I can't change the method into touchDown

The pan method by itself:

```java
@Override
        public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {

            for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++){//In case they drag wit second finger
                if(Gdx.input.isTouched(i) && Gdx.input.getX(i) < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2){
                    if(Gdx.input.getDeltaX(i) < - 3){
                        directionListener.onRight();
                        System.out.println(">");
                    }
                    if(Gdx.input.getDeltaX(i) > 3) {
                        directionListener.onLeft();
                        System.out.println("<");
                    }
                    finger = i;//used to stop body from rotating when the finger rotating it is lifted

                    System.out.println(i + " = " + Gdx.input.getX(i));
                }
            }

//Can't replace with touchdown because it does not override method from superclass

            return super.pan(x, y, deltaX, deltaY);
        }
```

The entire class:

```java
package com.doppelganger.spacesoccer.Helpers;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.input.GestureDetector;

public class SimpleDirectionGestureDetector extends GestureDetector{

    public static int finger = 10;

    public interface DirectionListener {
        void onLeft();

        void onRight();
    }

    public SimpleDirectionGestureDetector(DirectionListener directionListener) {
        super(new DirectionGestureListener(directionListener));
    }

    private static class DirectionGestureListener extends GestureDetector.GestureAdapter {
        DirectionListener directionListener;

        DirectionGestureListener(DirectionListener directionListener){
            this.directionListener = directionListener;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {

            for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++){//In case they drag with second finger
                if(Gdx.input.isTouched(i) && Gdx.input.getX(i) < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2){
                    if(Gdx.input.getDeltaX(i) < - 3){
                        directionListener.onRight();
                        System.out.println(">");
                    }
                    if(Gdx.input.getDeltaX(i) > 3) {
                        directionListener.onLeft();
                        System.out.println("<");
                    }
                    finger = i;//used to stop body from rotating when the finger rotating it is lifted

                    System.out.println(i + " = " + Gdx.input.getX(i));
                }
            }
//Can't replace with touchdown because it does not override method from superclass
            return super.pan(x, y, deltaX, deltaY);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem, you are ignoring the input when you touch the right side of the screen. Here's the line:

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched(i) && Gdx.input.getX(i) < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2){
```

You could verify `Gdx.input.getX(i) < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2` inside on another if statement and add an else statement to check the right side, something like this:

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) {
    if (Gdx.input.getX(i) < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) {
        // POINTER ON LEFT SIDE - SAME CODE
            if(Gdx.input.getDeltaX(i) < - 3) {
                directionListener.onRight();
                System.out.println(">");
            }
            if(Gdx.input.getDeltaX(i) > 3) {
                directionListener.onLeft();
                System.out.println("<");
            }
            finger = i; //used to stop body from rotating when the finger rotating it is lifted
            System.out.println(i + " = " + Gdx.input.getX(i));

    } else {
        // POINTER ON RIGHT SIDE - NEW CODE
        System.out.println("Right side");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the suggestion :D but I think you misunderstand, the problem is that the gesturedetector is not picking up input if the player is already touching the screen and they touch it again, I have code elsewhere in the game for when the user touches the right side of the screen which works fine. It's got to do with te gesturedetector not detecting multiple inputs. I tried your idea and it did nothing, so I'm just gonna try make my own input class and hope I can figure out something